# how to assign multiple localstorage variables inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, local-storage

im not familiar with localstorage...i need to assign a localstorage variable inside a loop...
e.g. :

```
localstorage.name1 = 'Mark';
localstorage.surname1 = 'fox';
localstorage.name2 = 'Chris';
localstorage.surname2 = 'Polt';
```

i tryied to do so but it wont work...
compiler says:

JavaScript Error:
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

```
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{ 
    localStorage.name = options['name'+i];
    localStorage.surname = options['surname'+i];
}
```

also, i need to do this in plain javascript, no jquery or other JS Frameworks.

Comment: Please define "it wont work"!

Comment: sorry. compiler just says "JavaScript Error:
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"

Comment: That error would suggest the problem is elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/0zt20qcb/

Comment: Yes the code you posted will not trigger that error message; nothing is trying to set property `0` of anything.

Comment: my guess: localStorage['name'+i]=options[i];

Comment: i solved with localStorage.setItem property. thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the property in the localStorage object?

```
localStorage.setItem(propName, value);
```

It prints `undefined` because you never set 'name1' and 'surname1' as a property in `localStorage`.
Your could set it like so:

```
if (!localStorage.name1) {
    localStorage.setItem("name1", "Mark");
    localStorage.setItem("surname1", "fox");
    localStorage.setItem("name2", "Chris");
    localStorage.setItem("surname2", "Polt");
}
```